# Cooling off food: "blow the soup" or "blow at the soup"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, articles, phrase-request

You have a bowl of hot soup / a stick of cold ice cream.

How do you express that you want **to cool it off** / **warm it up** by sending air from your mouth to it?

Is it accurate to say

1. "to blow **the** soup to cool it off" OR "to blow **at the** soup to cool it off"
2. "to blow **the** ice cream to warm it up" OR "to blow **at the** ice cream to warm it up"

Comment: I use "blow on it".

Comment: For (hard, scooped) ice cream you would 'let it stand' or "allow it to stand' to give it some time to soften (or thaw).

Comment: @BruceMurray, the air from our mouth is warm and thus help to warm the ice cream up. Can I say "to blow on the ice cream"?

Comment: Yes, but I have never encountered this behaviour with ice cream. For me, it's bizarre, but I live in Brazil and ice cream is always melting immediately straight from the fridge

Comment: Blowing on the ice cream will merely melt the outer layer, leaving the core to be still as frozen hard as it was. Best to let it stand, and for the thawing to be gradual; hence (assuming a temperate enough environment) the ice cream cools more uniformly. But this is a question for StackExchange Physics, not English Language Learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my table manners were indeed that appalling, I'd "blow *on* my soup" to cool it.

Never thought of doing something similar to ice-cream, the whole point of ice-cream is to eat it when it's as cold as possible.